# Find out Endpoints of Legacy PHP Codebase

Tags: php, reverse-engineering, endpoint

I have inherited a Magento store that I would like to replace with a new store system. Dealing with moving the products and so on is not the issue.

What makes it difficult is that there are some custom Magento modules that act as endpoints for outside HTTP requests. I was already able to find two of those "endpoints" hidden in the codebase but I am not sure if there more.

To not break that behaviour I need to find and replace all those URL routes.

I am searching for a "catch all requests" approach, ideally with PHP where I can log all incoming requests and then step-by-step identify the knowns/unknowns.

Is there a way to do this with htaccess or so?

Thanks!

Comment: There is. You could also just look in `access.log`. There you have exactly this information.